# Где опечатка и как исправить?

Tags: лексика, семантика

Восьмиклассница принесла задание с "Медвежонка".

> Одна из строф стихотворения испанского поэта Бартоломе Торреса Наарро
>   «Мне выпала в жизни такая дорога...» (перевод Анатолия Гелескула)
>   часто цитируется в таком виде:
>
> При жизни покоюсь, покоя не зная,
>
> лежит моё время без тени движенья,
>
> бессмертием тешится слава земная,
>
> и празднует сердце свои пораженья...
>
> Приведённый текст содержит опечатку, существенно искажающую смысл
>   написанного. Какое слово необходимо исправить, чтобы стихотворение
>   приобрело изначальный вид?

Она исправила, но не так. А как и что исправили бы  вы?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Да, всего лишь одна буковка, — а как меняется смысл!

*Мне выпала в жизни такая дорога,

что вижу я путь и вслепую плутаю,

и жив остаюсь, умирая до срока,

и весел на вид, когда слёзы глотаю.*

С первых стихотворных строк идут противопоставления: автор и видит, и плутает вслепую, и умер до срока, и жив — одновременно... Разнополюсные определения или сравнения (я бы назвала этот прием так) используются на всем протяжении стиха.
В вашем отрывке: покойная жизнь беспокойна, лежащее время бездвижно... Стоп. Но мы и так знаем: то, что лежит, не движется, — здесь нет противопоставления!

Думаю, что вторая строчка должна звучать так:
*ле**т**ит моё время без тени движенья...*

Бездвижное время летит — мне кажется, что именно это подразумевал автор.

Comment: Интересно, что слово *бездвижный* не удается найти в словарях, но в Нацкорпусе оно встречается.

Comment: Совершенно верно, а за ученицу мне тоже обидно: она исправила на " бежит", но ответ не засчитали, а могли бы засчитать. У нас опыт анализа текста, у неё - никакого, в том числе и жизненного. "Лежит" на "бежит" - очень неплохо для 8 класса, но ведь там ключи, им легче.

Answer (score 0):

Не "при жизни покоюсь", а "при жизни покоясь". "При жизни покоясь, покоя не зная" - два "нанизывающихся" деепричастных оборота, из которых по смыслу один исключает другой. Это исходит из логики предложения: далее "Лежит моё время" - "время" - подлежащее, "лежит" - сказуемое. Все остальные члены предложения имеют отношение только к ним! "Лежит как, каким образом?" - "покоясь". А "покоюсь" - это сказуемое в предложении типа: "я покоюсь". "Я что делаю? - Покоюсь." Никакой философии, только языковая логика!

Comment: Светлана, версия интересна, только вот что говорит Ваша языковая логика о времени, которое лежит? Есть подлежащее, есть сказуемое, но о чём они говорят? Может ли время лежать или оно всё-таки летит (так у автора, а по версии ученицы - бежит)?

Comment: Здесь сплошные анититезы и оксюмороны:  я   покоюсь, покоя не зная, время летит без тени движенья, бессмертие и  слава земная,сердце  празднует  пораженья...